# Prolog binary counter

Tags: prolog

i'm trying to do a program that counts the sequence of binary numbers, let me give an example
the input is [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
The output should be [0(the first number),3(number of 0 in sequence),2 (number of 1 in sequence),3,4]
the input size is infinite and it needs to be a list, so far what I have done is this:

```
list([H|T],[X|Y]):-
    T = [], X is H, Y is 1.

list([H|T],[X|Y]):-
    T \= [], X is H,X1 is 1, contlist([H|T],[X1,Y]).
    
contlist([H|T],[X,_]):-
    T \= [], 
    H =:= [T|_},
    T1 i
    contlist([H|T],[X,_]):-
    X1 is X+1.
```

I don't know how to compare the head with the head of the tail and how to continue from there, maybe someone can help me?

Comment: Why does it go from "0 (number of 0s)" to "2 (number of 1s)"? Instead of "1 (number of 1s)". And what are [3,4] doing on their own, should they be `0(3)` and `1(4)`? i.e. is this Run Length Encoding (RLE) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+run+length+encoding ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: this is a special case of RLE when your input is a binary sequence. In this case you only need to output the first digit and then just the sequence computed from the RLE but not the actual bits as every time you restart the run-length you know the input has flipped the bit (0 to 1 or 1 to 0)

Comment: @gusbro oh interesting, I hadn't heard of it but it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of Run-length encoding suitable for binary sequences.

You begin noting the first bit and start counting either 1s or 0s, when the bit flips you "output" the number and start counting the other bit value. Every time the sequence flips bits you output the number and start counting again until the whole sequence is processed. Note this procedure is not reversible. To make it reversible you would probably want to use clp(FD).

```
rle_binary([B|Seq], [B|BRLE]):-
  binary(B),
  rle_binary(Seq, B, 1, BRLE).
  
rle_binary([], _, N, [N]).
rle_binary([B|Seq], B, N, BRLE):-
  succ(N, N1),
  rle_binary(Seq, B, N1, BRLE).
rle_binary([B1|Seq], B, N, [N|BRLE1]):-
  binary(B1),
  B \= B1,
  rle_binary(Seq, B1, 1, BRLE1).

binary(0).
binary(1).
```

Sample run:

```
?- rle_binary( [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1], BRLE).
BRLE = [0, 3, 2, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

Comment: Why do you put
"N == 0 -> BRLE=[] ; BRLE=[N]."
in line 6, instead of just "BRLE=[N]."?

Comment: You are right, N will never be 0 so it is not needed. I just updated the answer to simplify the base case of `rle_binary/4`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is **[Run-Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)**.

It's easy to implement. Executing the below code as

```
?- run_length_encoding( [a,b,b,c,c,c] , Rs ) .
```

Yields

```
Rs = [ a:1, b:2, c:3 ]
```

[The code doesn't care what the list contains (outside of perhaps unbound variables)]

You can fiddle with it at: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/PrtWEfZx.pl

```
run_length_encoding( Xs, Ys ) :- nonvar(Xs), ! , rle_encode(Xs,Ys) .
run_length_encoding( Xs, Ys ) :- nonvar(Ys),     rle_decode(Ys,Xs) .
    
rle_encode( []     , [] ) .
rle_encode( [X|Xs] , Rs ) :- rle_encode(Xs,X:1,Rs) .

rle_encode( [X|Xs] , Y:N , [Y:N|Rs] ) :- X \= Y   , ! , rle_encode(Xs,X:1,Rs) .
rle_encode( [X|Xs] , X:N ,      Rs  ) :- M is N+1 , ! , rle_encode(Xs,X:M,Rs) .
rle_encode( []     , X:N , [X:N]    ) .

rle_decode( []       , []     ) .
rle_decode( [X:N|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- N > 0, !, M is N-1, rle_decode([X:M|Xs],Ys) .
rle_decode( [_:0|Xs] ,    Ys  ) :-                     rle_decode(Xs,Ys) .
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SWI-Prolog predicates [clumped/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clumped/2) and [pairs_values/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=pairs_values/2):

```
rle([X|Xs], [X|V]) :-
    clumped([X|Xs], P),
    pairs_values(P, V).
```

Example:

```
?- rle([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1], L).
L = [0, 3, 2, 3, 4].
```